# @types/zepto prevents me from importing zepto itself

Tags: typescript, zepto, definitelytyped

I have installed `zepto` and `@types/zepto` packages in npm. If I install only `zepto` without types and import it like this:

```
import * as $ from 'zepto';
```

Everything works. But if I install `@types/zepto` as well, it's presence in the node_modules directory somehow breaks it. It says "`@types/zepto/index.d.ts` is not module". How do I load type definitions for Zepto?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) is probably worth a read for you. It will explain how type files work.

If you put [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/zepto/index.d.ts) fine in your types folder in your project it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

`@types/jquery`:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jquery/index.d.ts

`@types/zepto`:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/zepto/index.d.ts

In `@types/jquery`, it writes `export = jQuery`, while in `@types/zepto`, it only writes `declare var Zepto` and `declare var $`.

These are different.

`export` can be imported as modules, but `declare var` declare global stuff, thus you should not use anything like `import * as $ from 'zepto'` or `import $ from 'zepto`'. The `Zepto` and `$` are declared globally if you have `@types/zepto` installed.